# Rails Dynamic Forms with Cascading Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cocoon-gem

I am trying to implement some nested form elements that have values based on a select box value in the main form. As it stands right now when I make the selection in the main form it changes the values displayed in all currently displayed nested form, but when I click the button to add a new nested form element, the new form elements display values that are not based on the primary select. What I need is for any time the button is clicked to add a new nested form, the values in that form should be based on the select box in the main form.

Here are the steps and what is happening:

[image]

Here are the steps and the desired results:

[image]

Here is what my partial looks like. This is what is displayed when the "new" button is clicked:

```
<tr class="details_row nested-fields">
  <td><%= f.select :area_id, options_for_select(@areas.collect {|c| [ c.area_name, c.id ] }), {include_blank: true}, {:class => 'form-control area_select'} %></td>
  <td><%= f.select :product_id, options_for_select(@products.collect {|p| [ p.product_number, p.id ] }), {include_blank: true}, {:class => 'form-control product_select'} %></td>
  <td><%= f.number_field :quantity, class: 'form-control', "min" => 1 %></td>
  <td><%= f.select :accessory_id, options_for_select(@accessories.collect {|p| [ p.product_number, p.id ] }), {include_blank: true}, {:class => 'form-control accessory_select'} %></td>
  <td><%= f.text_field :notes, class: 'form-control' %></td>
  <td><%= link_to_remove_association '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>'.html_safe, f %></td>
</tr>
```

All of this action is when I'm creating a new record, here is the code from my controller for the new method:

```
  def new
    if current_user
      @estimate = Estimate.new
      @estimate.estimate_details.build
      @default_user = current_user.id
      @product_type = 3
      @areas = Area.where("product_type_id = ?", @product_type)
      @products = Product.select("product_number, id").where("product_type_id = ? AND active = 't' ", @product_type)
      @accessories = Product.select("product_number, id").where("product_type_id = ? AND active = 't' AND accessory = 't'", @product_type)
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You are not logged in.'
    end
  end
```

This is the method from the controller (the same controller as new above) that updates the select boxes:

```
  def update_select
    @product_type = params[:product_type_id]
    @areas = Area.where("product_type_id = ?", params[:product_type_id])
    @products = Product.where("product_type_id = ? AND active = 't'", params[:product_type_id])
    @accessories = Product.where("product_type_id = ? AND active = 't' AND accessory = 't'", params[:product_type_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I was thinking that @product_type would be set to the default in the "new" method of the controller. When the update_select method is run, it should update the @product_type and this would be used when the new elements were created...but that didn't work.

### Update

Here is my update_select.js. This does update the three select boxes in the nested form, but I have to add a dynamic form and then make a selection in the main form select box in order for the fields to be correct for the newly added form details.

```
$(".area_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "select_boxes/area", collection: @areas)) %>")
$(".product_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "select_boxes/product", collection: @products)) %>")
$(".accessory_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "select_boxes/accessory", collection: @accessories)) %>")
```

Here are the partials referenced by the above js:
Accessory:

```
<option value="<%= accessory.id %>"><%= accessory.product_number %></option>
```

Product:

```
<option value="<%= product.id %>"><%= product.product_number %></option>
```

Area:

```
<option value="<%= area.id %>"><%= area.area_name.titleize %></option>
```

And just for good measure here is the script that triggers the update_select

```
$ ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#product_type_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax
      url:'/estimates/new/update_select',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'script',
      data: {
        product_type_id: $("#product_type_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus} #{errorThrown}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic area select OK!")
```

Comment: Are you sure your code is reaching the update_select action in your controller? What does your update_select.js.erb file look like? This is where you'll change the options for your selects.

Comment: Hi @n_i_c_k. I'm sure it's getting to the update_select part of the controller because if I make a selection from the master select box, the other select boxes do update, they just don't provide the right data when I add a new nested form. I also put a debugger in the method and I can see the variables change based on the value of the select box, but for some reason these values don't make it to the new nested form.